# Changing the font for the List Preference

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a list preference in my application. 
Have extended with a custom list preference.

Now i would like to keep the font of the preference entries according to my styling . (Don't want to have it changed according to the Device's fond settings).

I don't want to change any UI but only the styling like font size , font type etc.

Is it possible to do so. ?

cheers,
Saurav

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom style in `XML`, in a `<resources>` tag (not the listView layout), and then in the **single item XML layout** you can add Style = "@Style/mystyle" etc.

For example, there is a style.xml file already in values, and you could add:

```
<style name="ListViewStyle" >
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
</style>
```

and then in the listView xml:

```
<TextView
        style="@style/ListViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/mainListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```